# Apache connections limit and redirecting users

Tags: apache

Is there a way to redirect users to a simple page if my connections reach a specified limit? Kinda like if twitter is swamped, you get presented a blue whale :)

I just want to protect my server from going down.

Thanks.
P.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it by apache itself but you can try to install firewalls

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/security_tips.html

```
Often the most effective anti-DoS tool will be a firewall or other operating-system configurations. For example, most firewalls can be configured to restrict the number of simultaneous connections from any individual IP address or network, thus preventing a range of simple attacks. Of course this is no help against Distributed Denial of Service attacks (DDoS).
```